# How to signal the end of input using Cntr+z in python?

Tags: python

Please help me figure out how to get to the back.
I need to create a program with a loop that will accept integers from the user and then show their sum.However, the input must be completed using a combination (cntr+z or cntl+d depending on the system).Also, the program should check if these are integers, if it should give an error, then the result and exit.And yet I do not understand how I can make the input end with pressing cntr+z or ctrl+d.Please help me figure it out.
Here is my code :

````
    number = 0
    sum = 0
    while True:
        try:
            listnum = input('Input numbers or press Enter to quit and get total sum: ')
        except EOFError:
            pass
        try:
            number = number + 1
            sum = sum + int(listnum)   
        except IOError:
            number = number - 1
            print('Error') 
            break
    print('The total of input is:',sum) 
main()```
````

Comment: I am not sure I understand why you would want to simulate the user closing Python. Once the script reaches its end it will stop on its own.

Comment: Well, you never print the quantity of numbers read (`number`), and so if you're not super interested in the input prompt text, this entire program could be `print('The total of input is:', sum(map(int, iter(input, ''))))`. Sending special characters to signal the end of input is unique to each terminal emulator.

Comment: Use `break` instead of `pass`?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 That would require an empty line at the end of the input.

Comment: Yes, I know that; I mean in general the task of adding up a bunch of numbers can be done pretty efficiently, without even any inadvisable "clever hacks."

Comment: *"I do not understand how I can make the input end with pressing cntr+z or ctrl+d"* - You do it by pressing cntr+z or ctrl+d.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 What kind of inadvisable "clever hacks" are you thinking of here?

Comment: @HeapOverflow - There's all sorts of things that are possible but not advisable, even in Python. Most of them stem from trying to cram an entire program into [one line](https://github.com/TigerhawkT3/small_scripts/blob/master/vintage_media.py).

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Sure, but the reason I asked what "are you thinking of **here**" is that I don't see what you were talking about **here**. It sounded like you considered something on this page to be an inadvisable "clever hack". Did I misunderstand?

Comment: @HeapOverflow - Yes; I meant that this task can be solved much more concisely while still adhering to reasonable Python style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sys.stdin` to read the input, in the below snippet the input is asked till you hit `ctrl+d`. This is then stored in `input_from_user`  where you can perform your validations.

```
>>> import sys
>>> input_from_user=sys.stdin.read()
1
2
3
>>> input_from_user
'1\n2\n3\n'
```

The program can now be something like

```
import sys

input_from_user=sys.stdin.read()
try:
    total=sum(map(int,input_from_user.splitlines()))
except ValueError:
    print('Error')
else:
    print('Total is', total)
```

Output

```
1
2
3
Total is 6
```

Not int case

```
1
2
a
Error
```

Comment: `sum(map(int, sys.stdin))`

Comment: I write and check the code through node++,I looked at the instructions on how to create a macro to run Python directly in note++.I do not know why but when I try to enter Cntr+Z (I have Windows) then enter the values ^Z in the command line and the code will not stay.Is it possible that the problem is that I don't use IDLE?

Comment: @Fifv10 - As I said in a comment on the question itself, those codes and key combinations are specific to the terminal/system. For that reason, I usually rely on a sentinel value within my program itself, usually an empty line. If this is for a school assignment, you might want to ask your teacher about the particular terminal emulator and environment where this is expected to work.

Comment: @Fifv10 Have you tried Ctrl+Z followed by Enter? (And of course replacing `pass` with `break`.)